# Is it possible to programatically click on RelativeLayout?

Tags: android

I implemented simple Listener to swipe actions on RelativeLayout. But I want to use my onClick method, and I don't know how to fire selecting Layout, I mean this Layout has

```
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

this background value to see that someone clicked on this layout.

This is my Listener

```
public interface SwipeListener<T> {
        boolean swipeLeft(T itemData);
        boolean swipeRight(T itemData);
        void onClick(ViewHolder holder);
        void onLongClick(ViewHolder holder);
}
```

I am getting reference to RelativeLayout form ViewHolder which I implemented, but I don't know how to fire selecting this layout in order to see ripple effect ?

Comment: A view has two methods for this, performClick() and callOnClick(). http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/view/View.html#performClick()

Comment: But both requires clicklistener. If I add clickListener they are confusing what to call.

Comment: You need a ClickListener to do something when you perform a click, but that has nothing to do with the click event itself, using callOnClick() should do what you ask for.

Comment: No because in OnClick method I am adding ClickListener and then I am using callOnClickl(). After first time everything is ok, but after second and next times application is using new ClickListner instead of SwipeListener which I implemented

Comment: Maybe you can show us the code in question, how you call it, instead of this not so useful interface definition.